# How to deploy Azure SQL database via service principal

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a requirement to deploy Azure SQL database via Service Principal

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to deploy Azure SQL database based via DACPAC and service principal through powershell or Azure devops: Azure SQL database dpeloyment tasks.

You can refer the below links for my blogs :

https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/11/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-1/
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/12/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-2/

Comment: They never mention how am I supposed to find a service principal name. Is it service principal App registration display name? In my case those connections are creating AR's with the same display name, so I can not grant permission in SQL for the user as external provider, because it needs to have unique name. Can you advise?

Comment: Hey, can you please confirm on which part are you asking about? Sorry, your ask is not clear to me

Comment: I am asking about this part `CREATE USER [<ServicePrincipalName>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`. Where do I get this name?

Comment: Assuming you have clientid, Go to Azure Active Directory->App registrations->find your application by using  client id